# How to sort files into new or existing folders based on timestamp

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I've got some IP cameras that are recording 1-2 files per minute based on detected movement and am looking for a way to automatically move a set of video files into a new or existing folder based on the file name which is in timestamp format. This would be done in Windows 7 at a particular time each day when the cameras are not recording.

If the folder does not already exist for newly created files (which would typically be the case with all but the first file of the hour), it would ideally be made based on the hour in which they were created (not last modified).

Would this be best done through the cmd or maybe a python script, and how? My guess would be that I would have to parse the hour/day/month/year from the file-name, check to see if the appropriate folder exists and if it doesn't create one, then move it.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you give a specific example, showing the filenames and folders?
It can be done either way, but cmd is probably quickest and doesn't require python to be installed.

Comment: I posted the a list of the files above. The file-names are in the format of year, month, day, hour, minute, second (not sure what the '1' at the beginning is for). The new directory can be anywhere really, but for example all of the files above were made during "2013-09-20-15" and could go into a folder of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Simple script, not recursive.

```
    @echo off
@rem USAGE: MoveIt FromDir ToDir

setlocal

    if "%1"=="" goto :Usage
    if "%2"=="" goto :Usage

    pushd "%~2"
    set target=%CD%
    popd

    pushd "%~1"
    set root=%CD%

rem xxYYYY MM DD HH MM SS
rem 1_2013-09-20_25-11-08
rem 0123456789.123456789.

    for %%a in (*) do call :MoveIt "%%a"

    goto :EOF

:MoveIt

    rem Extract just the filename (no path or extension)
    set name=%~n1

    rem Extract the hour
    set hour=%name:~13,2%

    rem Create the directory hourname
    if not exist "%hour%" mkdir "%hour%"

    rem Move the file
    echo move "%~1" "%target%\%hour%"
    goto :EOF

:Usage
    echo Usage: moveByTime.bat  RootDirectory TargetDirectory
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Joe! I'm a bit confused though, as I've never done anything nearly this complex in CMD or a .bat before. Will this sort all of the files of all hours from each day into their respective "by hour" directory? Is "CD" your place holder for the actual directory?

Comment: Also, does this take any arguments when I start it with "start moveByTime.bat"?

Comment: Two args: FromDir and ToDir.
So "moveit.bat C:\myfiles C:\yourfiles" will move all the files in C:\myfiles to C:\yourfiles\00\, C:\yourfiles\01\, C:\yourfiles\02\..... C:\yourfiles\23\

Comment: The PUSHD stuff: This is just to normalize the path so that if you give it a directory name like "..\..\foo\bar", it converts it to "C:\users\joe\documents\foo\bar". "%CD%" is a pseudo env var with the current directory path.

Comment: The syntax "%~n1" is documented in "call /?" and "set /?"

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little more straight forward.  Modify the 2nd and 3rd lines to suit your system and then place the batch file in your user folders somewhere and you can schedule it.

Test it on some sample files first.

```
@echo off
set "target=d:\monitoring video\backups"
pushd "c:\camera\videos folder"

for /f "tokens=5 delims=-_" %%a in (' dir /b /a-d ') do (
echo processing "%%a"
md "%target%\%%a" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%target%\%%a" >nul
)
popd
```

BTW, your requirement was to create an `hour` folder and move the appropriate files into it.  This means that files from hour 01 on every day will go into the same `01` folder.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Correct. Then hour02 to 02 folder.